# how to output youtube embedded videos with jquery toggle action?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I want to output youtube videos with a toggle on/off option by jquery on my website by retrieving youtube embed codes from my SQL table. I got the youtube videos to hide/display by clicking a button with javascript but I wanted the smooth transition that the jquery toggle action provides.

Heres what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hide/show iframe</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>

<style type="text/css">
<!--

.frDocViewer {
     width:70%;
     height:50%;
     display:none;
     }



-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
    $(id).toggle("slow");
  });
});


</script>

</head>
<body>



<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost","","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("") or die(mysql_error());

$lastid = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM embed ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$lastid = mysql_fetch_assoc($lastid);
$lastid = $lastid['id'];

for ($count=1; $count<= $lastid ; $count++)
{

$iframe = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM embed WHERE id=$count ");
$iframe = mysql_fetch_assoc($iframe);
$iframe = $iframe['url'];   




echo "
<img src='utube.gif' id='button'  />

<div id='$count' class='frDocViewer'>

$iframe

</div>
";





}







?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but it seems you are looking for the .fadeToggle() or .slideToggle() jQuery functions.

Those were included in jQuery 1.4.4 and work the same way as .toggle().

So that would be:

```
//fades from 0 opacity to 1
$(id).fadeToggle("slow");

//slides vertically from 0 to X height
$(id).slideToggle("slow");
```

Hope it helps!